# Voyager navbar padding problem when override

Tags: laravel, overriding, laravel-blade, voyager

**Problem:**
When I override my `voyager` view using a custom controller. I am getting a padding problem at the top:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reWWw.png)

**Desired output**
This is how it should be:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hULXF.png)

**My code**
browse.blade.php

```
@extends('voyager::master')

@section('content')

    @foreach($exploitants as $exploitant)
        {{ $exploitant->exp_nom }}<br>
    @endforeach

@endsection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<br>` inside a loop. It might the one causing the problem. Every browser interpret `<br>` differently. Try using a fixed `px` margins instead.

And change `@endsection>` to `@endsection`

Comment: Thanks. I'm embarrassed to say that it was the ">" that caused the problem